# jQuery ui-calendar next month button

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I've created two calendars (next to each other) in ui-calendar.
Calendars have two diffrent dates.

[image]

I'm trying to create a button which will make one month step on every one.

So if i click next button two calendars are getting +1 month.

However nothing seems to work with the function I've created.
Please take a look.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="calendar-wrapper">
        <div id="doubleCalendar1"></div>
        <button id="prev">Previous Month</button>&nbsp;
        <button id="next">Next month</button>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="calendar-wrapper">
         <div id="doubleCalendar2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>


function twoCalendars(day, month, year) {

jQuery('#doubleCalendar1').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    defaultDate: new Date(year,month,day),
    showOtherMonths: false,
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
});

jQuery('#doubleCalendar2').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    defaultDate: new Date(year,month + 1,day),
    showOtherMonths: false,
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
});

$('#next').on('click', function() {
    $('#doubleCalendar1 .ui-datepicker-next').trigger("click");
});
```

}

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger click for datepicker2 as well in your next button click listener.

Like this

```
$('#doubleCalendar2 .ui-datepicker-next').trigger("click");
```

Or you can just use .ui-datepicker-next class to trigger click event on both datepicker if there are no other datepicker except these 2

```
$('.ui-datepicker-next').trigger("click");
```

```js
function twoCalendars(day, month, year) {

  jQuery('#doubleCalendar1').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    defaultDate: new Date(year, month, day),
    showOtherMonths: false,
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
  });

  jQuery('#doubleCalendar2').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    defaultDate: new Date(year, month + 1, day),
    showOtherMonths: false,
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
  });

  $('#next').on('click', function() {
    $('.ui-datepicker-next').trigger("click");

  });
  
  $('#prev').on('click', function() {
    $('.ui-datepicker-prev').trigger("click");
  });

}

twoCalendars(10, 2, 2017);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="calendar-wrapper">
      <div id="doubleCalendar1"></div>
      <button id="prev">Previous Month</button>&nbsp;
      <button id="next">Next month</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="calendar-wrapper">
      <div id="doubleCalendar2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but nothing seems to work.

I've refactored a function:

$('#next').on('click', function() {
        $('.ui-datepicker-next').trigger("click");
    });

but it just not working

Comment: Ok my *censored* mistake.

The enviroment I'm working in doesn't accept dollar sign, only jQuery mark.

ehh...Wordpress